# Programming Problems and Concepts

Tags: c++

I have been studying programming, C++ specifically, for about 6 months and I got in a competition in my school. The teacher said that it will have some programming problems of different difficulties, although I have been working with problems like the ones found on Project Euler, I need different ones not just ones with math. Can anyone suggest any good problems, the more advanced the better. Or some books or articles I can read to improve my programming? I have googled this however answers are not as good as I expected and are really vague. I would really appreciate a solid and clear answer from experienced developers.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The subreddit [The Daily programmer](https://www.reddit.com/r/dailyprogrammer/) post challenges, well, daily.

They are categorized by level, so you can test yourself and see what level are you and even compete with others.

enjoy

Answer (score -2):

Check Herb Sutter's [Exceptional C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201615622) book, it has very good challenges. If you've already read it, there are sequels to that one as well, namely [More Exceptional C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/020170434X) and [Exceptional C++ Style](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201760428)